# Reading lines until specific line in c programming

Tags: c, arrays, file-io

I want to print lines until a specified line. Content of a text file is written on buffer array as you see below example. How can I print from first line to fifth or sixth line ?

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    char *buffer;
    int c;
    FILE *input;
    int i = 0;
    size_t buffer_size;

    input = fopen( "input.txt", "r");
    if ( input == NULL ) {
        perror("Error");
    }

    buffer_size = BUFSIZ;
    if ((buffer = malloc(buffer_size)) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error allocating memory (before reading file).\n");
        fclose(input);
    }


    while ((c = fgetc(input)) != EOF) {
        buffer[i++] = c;
    }

    //puts(buffer);


    fclose(input);  
    free(buffer);
    return 0;
}
```

Content of text file:

```
1 test
2 test
3 test test
4 test
5 test test
6 test
7 test
```

Comment: `if ( input == NULL )` is nice and safe, but you still continue reading from `input`. Use `fgets()` and don't use malloc like that, you didn't call `free()` so it means that `char buffer[BUFSIZ];` will do.

Comment: I think it's right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    FILE *input;
    int c, line, numOfLine = 0;

    printf("input line number : ");
    scanf("%d", &line);

    input = fopen("data.txt", "r");//Error handling is omitted

    while ((c = fgetc(input)) != EOF) {
        putchar(c);
        if(c == '\n' && ++numOfLine == line)
            break;
    }

    fclose(input);  
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to do it with [`fgets()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/ungetc.3.html) like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
 {
    char   buffer[BUFSIZ];
    FILE  *input;
    size_t lineCount;
    size_t maxLine;

    input = fopen("input.txt", "r");
    if (input == NULL)
     {
        perror("Error");
        return -1;
     }

    maxLine   = 5;
    lineCount = 0;
    while ((lineCount < maxLine) && (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), input) != NULL))
     {
        puts(buffer);
        lineCount += 1;
     }

    return 0;
 }
```

read the manual in the link to see why it works.

Comment: How can be maxLine found if it is not known ?

Comment: @user3674483 I don't know!!! why it is not known in the first place?, and you should be the one to answer that, i.e. establish a cirterion to stop iterating, but don't ask me.

Comment: @user3674483 `maxLine` is "specified line".

Comment: owh. sorry. Can I use the while loop in my code ? `while ((lineCount < maxLine) && (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), input) != NULL))`

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`getline()`](http://crasseux.com/books/ctutorial/getline.html) function. Additionally, you can also check for the occurrences of carriage return `\r` to determine the new lines. Keep track of the count and you will be able to print up to your desired line.

Comment: `getline()` is `POSIX` and some OS's don't support that. Also, `'\r'` is a os specific extra character at the end of lines, it's from the OS's that do not support `getline()`.